# How to open Live Agent prechat form in a new tab, instead of a popup

Tags: liveagent

Live Agent currently opens the Prechat form in a popup window. I want to open the Prechat in a new Tab instead.

The popup window can get lost behind users' other windows. The popup window also doesn't flash or anything when a chat is connected. This is a problem because if a customer is waiting 5 minutes to be connected to a chat, they need to be reminded when they are connected, or else they might not notice while they're checking their email.

This is the only setting I can find regarding the Live Agent window size. No option to open it as a new tab, as opposed to a popup:
        liveagent.setChatWindowHeight(590);
        liveagent.setChatWindowWidth(500);

If the customer has the chat as a Tab, I'm hoping I can make the tab flash when a new chat comes in. That way the customer will see it. I also plan on playing a noise when the chat is connected, which would be a nice Out-of-the-box feature, too.

But how to have it as a tab?

UPDATE: After some research, having the chat open in a tab is difficult, so I'd prefer to bring Focus to the popup window when the agent sends their first message. I have an event I can use to trigger javascript when the agent sends their first message, but I don't know how to write javascript that will successfully bring focus to the popup (bring it to the front of their browser windows). I've looked into window.opener but I don't see how to use window.opener with the live agent environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[startChatWithWindow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_launching_chat_request_API_startChatWithWindow.htm)**.

In this method you can provide window name, You can create blank window / tab and provide reference to this window in above method.

Other resources :

- [Live Agent developer guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/live_agent_dev/live_agent_dev_guide.pdf)
- [Video on setting up live agent (Basic)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yBZUoHmAEiM)

Comment: Do you have a snippet of this working? Opening a tab is a setting that is normally controlled by the user so I don't think this can work.

Comment: I researched startChatWithWindow, but I'm not sure how I'd use it. Does startChatWithWindow open a window with a certain name, or do you have to create the window first, and then pass the name to startChatWithWindow? We also have 2 different button IDs, so it may be difficult. I'm going to amend my question to discuss how to bring focus to the popup when an agent first starts typing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `liveagent.chasitor.Events.CHAT_ESTABLISHED` event to bring attention of the user. Sometimes back I have also tried to implement similar solution, but could not found a cross-browser solution to highlight the minimized window or to bring it to focus.

As a workaround I am playing a sound file when Agent accepts the chat. Please find the below code snippet on how to do this. Also there is a default sound available when Agent starts typing. Hope this helps.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var audio = new Audio('http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/demo/audio_file.mp3');
    liveagent.addEventListener(liveagent.chasitor.Events.CHAT_REQUEST_SUCCESSFUL,myCallBack);
    liveagent.addEventListener(liveagent.chasitor.Events.CHAT_ESTABLISHED,newagent);


    function myCallBack() {
          var details = liveagent.chasitor.getDetails();
        //..
    }
    function newagent() {
      var details = liveagent.chasitor.getDetails();
      audio.play();
    }    
</script>
```